# GAE: RunQuery required more quota than is available despite having plenty of quota remaining

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-quotas

I'm getting the following exception from a query that was working just fine up until a few moments ago:

```
OverQuotaError: The API call datastore_v3.RunQuery() required more quota than is available.
```

However, in the quota details it's not showing us as being over any quotas related to the datastore:

[image: screenshot of storage quota detail]

Any idea what might be causing this OverQuotaError?

Comment: Hi Greg! Couple questions : 1- Was that query part of a lot of queries ran in quick succession? Because while you have the daily quota, there is also the per minute quota that can stop you. 2- Is it possible you've hit the limit of your daily budget and that was what was causing issues?

Comment: Hi @Patrice - 1. It was a single query that was run without other queries running in quick succession. 2. I'm not a billing administrator on the account; is it possible to determine if we were at our limit for daily budget without being a billing admin?

Comment: Hmmmm, I believe that you can see it from the dashboard (in your developer console, under " Compute->App Engine->Dashboard"). There is a "biling status" section, which should contain both your daily budget, and what you're at right now. Not sure who it's available too, as I'm billing admin on all my projects. In any case, it'll be easy to see if this is what's happening, as the same query should now work (the daily budget reset since then)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Datastore, you should make sure that your App Engine budget is also able to handle any Datastore usage above the [Free Quota](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=en#Datastore).

In particular, it looks like you are at 50K Datastore Read operations for the day. This is the maximum amount of daily free quota you receive for read operations. At this point any billable operations must be within your [App Engine Budget](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=en#Safety_Quotas_and_Billable_Quotas). You can follow the instructions on the [quotas page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=en#Safety_Quotas_and_Billable_Quotas) for increasing your daily budget, which will allow you to exceed the Datastore free quota.